# Unable to Find the Entry point to a function in a dll

Tags: c#, dllimport

I have a function in C++ COM dll

```
Write( Const VARIANT *pData);
```

where VARIANT is a struct Type

```
struct VARIANT 
{
unsigned short vt;
unsigned short wReservered;
 .....

};
```

I have to call this write function from my C# code and a multidimensional array is to be passed to the function. I am doing the marshalling as follows ..

c++ code

---

in header file :

```
LBE.h
class CLBE
{
public: 

 __declspec(dllexport) HRESULT __stdcall Write (/*[in]*/ const VARIANT* pData);

}
```

where VARIANT is a struct Type

```
struct VARIANT 
{
 unsigned short vt;
 unsigned short wReservered;
 .....

};
```

LBE.cpp

```
extern "C"
{

__declspec(dllexport) HRESULT __stdcall Write (const VARIANT* pData)
{

//impl
}
}
```

c# code

---

```
namespace abc 

public class dataarea 
{


[DLLImport("sample.dll",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint = "Write")]
public static extern int Write ([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref object pData);

.
.
.

public saveobject()
{

    object[,] pVariant;
    //  populating pVariant 
    object tempVar = pVarriant;
    Write(ref tempVar);
    }
  }
```

But when I call the write function from c# it throws an error saying " unable to find the entry point " write". Could anyone resolve this issue?

Comment: check if the dll and your project are both 32 or 64 bit

Comment: I see discrepancy in your code. In the `LBE.h` file you have a class with a `Write` method, and in your `.cpp` file you have a global `Write` method. Which one do you want to call?

Comment: its the same Write Method .. sorry for not writing it in detail